# Internet Explorer compability view / IIS7 issue?

Tags: asp.net, html, visual-studio, internet-explorer, iis

My webpage code is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>index</title>    
</head>
<body style="background-color: Black;" >
</body>
</html>
```

When I run the page on my development Pc (Visual Studio 2010), I get this result:

[image]

Notice that the page is rendered in compability mode.

When I run the exact same page from IIS7, I get this result:

[image]

Now the compability view is gone, but I now have a vertical scrollbar and a white frame (1-2 pixels) around the entire page (see the yellow arrows - it might be hard to see here).

Here's my questions:

1. Why is compability view different when running in development than on my IIS7 production server?
2. With the HTML code above, why is there a vertical scrollbar and a small frame around the page? ... and how do I get rid of it? I want an entire black page.

Thank you in advance!

Mojo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of `<!DOCTYPE html>` normally prevents compatibility mode, but for local files (localhost:...), IE tends to use compatibility mode despite it. To override this, use

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

(which may have various other effects too), or test your pages on a server.

Answer (score 0):

put this linebefore the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```